# Why using p:nth-child(3n+0) css pseudo class starts with the 2nd element?

Tags: css

I'm playing with new CSS3 selectors and pseudo class and I'm trying to use the :nth-child pseudo class.

If I look the documentation here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

I see and example with :

```
p:nth-child(3n+0)
{
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

But if I look the result ( http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_nth-child_formula ), I don't understand why the first red element is the second one and not the third or the first.

What is the logic behind this ?

Comment: nope, if this was the case, it would have select the first or the fourth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second paragraph *is* the third child:

```
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<p>The first paragraph.</p>
<p>The second paragraph.</p>
```

if you wanted to start with the third paragraph, try [`:nth-of-type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead:

```
p:nth-of-type(3n){
    background: #F00
}
```

W3Schools isn't always the clearest resource, and [sometimes it's very wrong](http://w3fools.com). Be careful when using it.

Comment: you're right ! I was missing the "The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent." And good to know that W3schools is not a really good ressource, I was very confident about it :(